# Federal Stafford Loan deferment options?

Tags: united-states, loans, student-loan

I have a question pertaining to Federal Stafford Loans, I think it goes here, let me know otherwise.

I have several student loans, Federal Stafford Loans to be exact, and the National Guard has agreed to pay essentially 1/6th of the loans every anniversary of my entry date with them.

Is it possible to place the loans in deferment after a bulk payment of that type?

What are the ramifications to my credit/personal financial well-being of doing so?

The reason I ask is that I received warning order from my unit, and will not be able to manage my payments etc. from abroad, and automatic payments isn't exactly an option at this point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the lender that holds the student loans and ask them about deferring them. From my understanding there is no deferment based solely on being in the national guard, but there are special provisions for soldiers called to active duty that should allow you to defer the loans (may require a copy of your orders). The deferment period should be the length of time you are on active duty plus 180 days post deployment/active duty.

Make sure that you stay current on your student loans if you don't get a deferment because most student loan forgiveness programs require that you're current as a condition for forgiveness.